# How can I send a Carousel like message in Telegram bot?

Tags: php, telegram-bot

I've been searching for something like this https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/800/1*pLXaOT2WwxRptVxOvuvX8w.png in Telegram to no avail. Anyone out there can point me to the right direction? Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem that Telegram supports that kind of functionality right now. What it has though are the custom Inline Keyboards, which provide the user with several buttons he can press, and then you can access the selected value by using the callback_data property. More can be found in this section of the documentation: [Telegram API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inline-mode). Hope this helps.